# Rotate 2D object with text input in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a aircraft radar simulation in Unity. I am trying to rotate the "aircraft" through text input and buttons.

The flow is as follows:
Input 270 degrees > Use mouse to click either Turn Left or Turn Right > aircraft rotates to the position 270 degrees

Assume 360 degrees is always pointing north. So if you Turn Left to the position of 270 degrees, you will take a shorter time to rotate to that position than Turing Right to the position of 270 degrees.

The aircraft is a green circle

[image: What the game looks like]

I was able to get the Left and Right buttons to rotate the aircraft, however the degrees is hardcoded in the c# script.

Left Button:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Left : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
{
    bool ispressed = false;
    public GameObject Aircraft;

    void Update()
    {
        if (ispressed)
        {
            Aircraft.transform.Rotate(-90.0f, 0, 0, Space.World);
        }
    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ispressed = true;
    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ispressed = false;
    }
}
```

Right Button:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Right : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
{
    bool ispressed = false;
    public GameObject Aircraft;

    void Update()
    {
        if (ispressed)
        {
            Aircraft.transform.Translate(0.2f, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ispressed = true;
    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ispressed = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value entered in the input field,
Here's a simple way:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Left : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
{
    bool ispressed = false;
    public GameObject Aircraft;
    public InputField dataInput;
    private float _degree => int.Parse(dataInput.text);

    void Update()
    {
        if (ispressed)
        {
            Aircraft.transform.Rotate(-_degree, 0, 0, Space.World);
        }
    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ispressed = true;
    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ispressed = false;
    }
}
```

After writing the following, you can get the value by entering the corresponding input field in the inspector window.

This is a very simple method, and there are some caveats.
If you put a value other than a number in the data, it is recognized as an unintended value.
If you want to put only numbers, you can also set it as the Content Type of the input field.

Comment: Could you kindly clarify what you meant by "you can get the value by entering the corresponding input field in the inspector window.".  Are you perhaps talking about the "On Value Changed (string)" of the input field?

Comment: Yes, that's right. 'public InputField dataInput;' , and the variable appears in the inspector window. After dragging and dropping the input field in the Hierarchy window to the variable, By modifying the value of an input field, you can get the value of that input field.

Comment: I'm probably not doing something right as I get this error: Assets\_MyProject\Scenes\Linus test\Linus scripts\Left.cs(12,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InputField' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

I put the Aircraft in the On Value Changed (String) on the input field, is that correct?

Comment: Oh I forgot using. I re-edited the code and uploaded it.

Comment: I put the Left and Right scripts in the Aircraft, I can slot in the aircraft into the variable however not the Inputfield...